# How to embed ads in WP7 app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, ads

I want to know how to embed ad frame into my WP7/WP7.1 application.

I also want to know places that I can get the ads from to put in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need to know is provided [right here by Microsoft](https://advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps). The control is included in the Windows Phone SDK and can be dropped right into your app (`AdControl` in the Visual Studio Toolbox).

You cannot directly control which ads are shown but you can influence it in some way (cited from FAQ):

> As noted above, the most relevant ads will also be the most likely
>   ones to get you the most revenue. So the same advice holds true:
>
> 1. If your app is location-aware, provide that info to the Ad Control.
> 2. Set as many of the demographic targeting properties in the Ad Control as you can for each user.
> 3. Set the right category for the Ad Unit in pubCenter.
> 4. If you have a set of relevant ad keywords, set those in the Ad Control.

For more tutorials I strongly suggest a Google/Bing search as there are plenty of these.

Answer (score 2):

Also, once you get the hang of using this AdControl, take a look at AdRotator (on CodePlex), as well as AdDuplex (AdDuplex.com).  With AdRotator, you can rotate MS ads, Google ads, AdDuplex ads (to trade advertising other people's apps for them advertising yours).  This can be beneficial to you, depending on what part of the world you are targeting.  Not every country can see MS ads yet, so if you are targeting outside of MS's supported countries, this can help you.  Also, you can configure AdRotator using an XML file on your web server, so you can change your ad mix by changing the XML file, and not have to push a new version of your app just to change ad mix.